# How to add a contextual action link to a View?

Tags: views, 8, navigation

I want to replace the default EntityListBuilder from a custom entity with a View, as it is much quicker to build that list interface with it.

However I want to retain the action button from the EntityListBuilder on the View itself, which is in the `links.action.yml`:

```
entity.room.add_form:
  route_name: entity.room.add_form
  title: 'Add Room'
  appears_on:
    - entity.room.collection
```

Would I just add the view identifier under `appears_on`? What would the format be for that string?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Figured it out not long after posting. The format is view.(view_id).(display_id):

```
entity.room.add_form:
  route_name: entity.room.add_form
  title: 'Add Room'
  appears_on:
    - entity.room.collection
    - view.rooms.rooms_admin
```